# SSRS report fails to render via URL access unless View Report is clicked

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rendering, ssrs-2012

The hyperlink to my SSRS report correctly renders parameters passed in on the URL query string. But the report does not render unless the View Report button is clicked. Other reports render as expected so I suspect something is wrong with the URL of the problem report:

```
http://reportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSales+Mgr+Reports%2fCustomer+Product+Variance+with+Net+Margin+Report&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rs:Command=Render&ReportType=PD&SortType=P&CurBeginDate=04/15/2013&CurEndDate=04/15/2014&CusCode=XXXXXXXXXX
```

That URL correctly fills the reports required parameters:

[image]

**Why does this report fail to render even though I've included the command `rs:Command=Render`?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind...I figured it out. Someone else might benefit though...

**Blank parameters cannot be omitted from the query string.** The two blank parameter boxes (Product Desc and Product ID) must be passed in with no value in order to make the render command work. It appears this is necessary even though those parameters are not required to run the report.

So the working query string has two (blank) parameters added on the end and looks like this:

```
http://reportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSales+Mgr+Reports%2fCustomer+Product+Variance+with+Net+Margin+Report&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&ReportType=PD&SortType=P&CurBeginDate=04/15/2013&CurEndDate=04/15/2014&CusCode=XXXXXXXXXX&ProdDesc=&ProdID=
```